# Can't deploy uWSGI Python Script: Mount Point = 0

Tags: linux, debian, python, uwsgi, supervisord

When I run my application I get the following error:

```
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
```

The command I use to run it is this:

```
/usr/local/bin/uwsgi -L -w app:app --ini /etc/configuration/uwsgi/uwsgi.ini --uid deploy
```

My [uWSIG](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/CGI.html) configuration looks like this:

```
[uwsgi]
socket = 127.0.0.1:8001
master = true
processes = 1
pidfile = /tmp/app-uwsgi.pid
chdir = /etc/application
```

My supervisor configuration looks like this:

```
[unix_http_server]
file=/tmp/supervisor.sock   ; (the path to the socket file)

[supervisord]
logfile=/var/log/supervisord.log                  ; (main log file;default $CWD/supervisord.log)
logfile_maxbytes=50MB                             ; (max main logfile bytes b4 rotation;default 50MB)
logfile_backups=10                                ; (num of main logfile rotation backups;default 10)
loglevel=info                                     ; (log level;default info; others: debug,warn,trace)
nodaemon=false                                    ; (start in foreground if true;default false)
minfds=1024                                       ; (min. avail startup file descriptors;default 1024)
minprocs=200                                      ; (min. avail process descriptors;default 200)
; user=supervisor_user                            ; Running as root is better than nothing

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///tmp/supervisor.sock             ; use a unix:// URL  for a unix socket

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[program:app]
command=/usr/local/bin/uwsgi -L -w app:app --ini /etc/configuration/uwsgi/uwsgi.ini --uid deploy
stdout_logfile=/var/log/uwsgi.log
redirect_stderr=true
stopsignal=INT
autorestart=true
priority=800
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get this working I needed to specify the virtualenv location in the uwsgi ini, then it worked just fine